# Unable to retrieve correct data from Titan using Gremlin

Tags: java, titan

I am connecting to Titan (Using titan-all-0.4.4) from java as

```
TitanGraph g = TitanFactory.open("/titan-all-0.4.4/conf/titan-cassandra.properties");
```

Where `titan-cassandra.properties` is the default file that comes with Titan.

I am trying to insert vertices in Graph g as,

```
Vertex a = g.addVertex(null);
a.setProperty("name", "a");
Vertex b = g.addVertex(null);
b.setProperty("name", "b");
Vertex c = g.addVertex(null);
c.setProperty("name", "c");
Vertex d = g.addVertex(null);
d.setProperty("name", "d");
g.commit();`
```

I then query through Gremlin as,

```
g = TitanFactory.open("/titan-all-0.4.4/conf/titan-cassandra.properties");
g.V.count()
```

The `g.V.count()` (or in general any other function like `g.V.map()`) returns at times a correct value (or data), at times incorrect. Eg. Count value is 4 in the above program, but sometimes `g.V.count()` returns 1, at times 4. I also do `g.V.map()` to verify and it is in accordance with count. (at times not all data is retrieved, at times it just works fine)

How should I confirm whether the data that I am trying to add to my graph is actually added and confirm that by querying through gremlin?

Comment: Sounds like some kind of cassandra problem.

Comment: Are you just getting started with Titan? Version 1.0 released in September. http://titandb.io

Comment: I'm new to Titan, I downloaded the Titian/All 0.4.4 (scroll down the page, there's a table) present on [Github link](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Downloads). Do you think that there's some problem with cassandra/Titan? (Also at times g.V.count() shows zero value in spite of inserting vertices)

Answer (score 0):

So I solved this problem by installing new Titan 0.5.2. And now the data is getting inserted properly. Probably there was some issue with Titan 0.4.4 version.

Comment: Nice. Why not 0.5.4 at least? Titan is an open source project. If you're just getting started, I'd recommend using 1.0 since that is the latest available and most likely to get support and fixes.